# the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not float

Tags: python, pandas

df_json:

```
filedate    code    errorID rawrecord                                                                                                                                   errortype
20230811    8003    100     {"Action":"NEW","ID":"30811-195552-952","EventType":"MMMM","Date":"20230811T000000.000000","orderID":"111111111111","price":12.0000}        BBBB
20230811    8003    101     {"Action":"NEW","ID":"20811-195555-952","EventType":"MMMM","Date":"20230811T000000.000000","orderID":"111111111112","price":18.0000}        BBBB
20230811    8003    102     {"Action":"NEW","ID":"50811-195552-952","EventType":"MMMM","Date":"20230811T000000.000000","orderID":"411111111111","price":12.0000}        BBBB
20230811    8003    103     {"Action":"NEW","ID":"60811-195552-952","EventType":"MMMM","Date":"20230811T000000.000000","orderID":"511111111111","price":19.0000}        BBBB
20230811    8003    104     {"Action":"NEW","ID":"40811-195552-952","EventType":"MMMM","Date":"20230811T000000.000000","orderID":"611111111111","price":10.0000}        BBBB
20230811    8003    105     {"Action":"NEW","ID":"80811-195552-952","EventType":"MMMM","Date":"20230811T000000.000000","orderID":"811111111111","price":12.0000}        BBBB
20230811    8003    106     {"Action":"NEW","ID":"70811-195552-952","EventType":"MMMM","Date":"20230811T000000.000000","orderID":"911111111111","price":17.0000}        AAAA
```

when I try to load this I get the error

```
"the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not float"
```

I am trying to extract key value pair from a column rawrecord.

```
df_json=df_json.join(df_json['rawrecord'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(json.loads(x))))
```

I tried to use json.dumps(), json.load() but its not working.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: `"price"=12.0000` is not valid JSON. that could be part of the issue. try replacing `=` with `:`

Comment: In addition to the above comment correctly noting that the way your `price` fields are entered isn't actually JSON syntax at all -- the error message means you have a number in a field that you're trying to parse as JSON. Are you sure that _every_ `rawrecord` is in fact a string?

Comment: I'm assuming `"price"=12.0000` is just a typo. You probably have `NaN` in the column. Try to filter the dataframe before.

Comment: sorry it was my mistake.. it is : and not =.. and there is no NaN as well

Comment: the rawrecord is a string column.

Comment: @AndrejKesely.. so if i give this df_json = df_json.fillna(value='')  before i apply json.loads() then I get error " Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" .

Comment: @unicorn So yes, you have `NaN`s in your column. You can try to fill them with `df_json.fillna(value='{}')`

Comment: @AndrejKesely.. perfect. this worked .. i didnt know there were NaN as i couldnt see any NaN values. thank you ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve this by handling null before applying json.loads().

```
df_json.fillna(value='{}')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `rawrecord` column is treating the contents as strings instead of `dict`, you first neet to use `literal_eval` to convert string to `dict`.

```
import ast
df['rawrecord'] = df['rawrecord'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
```

After that you can use [pd.json_normalise](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to get the data in multiple columns:

```
pd.json_normalize(df['rawrecord'])
# pd.concat([df, pd.json_normalize(df['rawrecord'])],axis=1) # if you want to concatas well
```

Output:

```
  Action                ID EventType                    Date       orderID  \
0    NEW  30811-195552-952      MMMM  20230811T000000.000000  111111111111   
1    NEW  20811-195555-952      MMMM  20230811T000000.000000  111111111112   
2    NEW  50811-195552-952      MMMM  20230811T000000.000000  411111111111   
3    NEW  60811-195552-952      MMMM  20230811T000000.000000  511111111111   
4    NEW  40811-195552-952      MMMM  20230811T000000.000000  611111111111   
5    NEW  80811-195552-952      MMMM  20230811T000000.000000  811111111111   
6    NEW  70811-195552-952      MMMM  20230811T000000.000000  911111111111   

   price  
0   12.0  
1   18.0  
2   12.0  
3   19.0  
4   10.0  
5   12.0  
6   17.0
```

Comment: thank you very much.. i had NaN value and it worked when i gave the df_json.fillna(value='{}')

Comment: @unicorn you're welcome, can you accept the answer?